# XML editing with Eclipse for C/C++ and XMLEspresso

Tags: xml, eclipse

I needed a cross platform XML editor and a modern IDE for C and Python, so I installed Eclipse for C/C++, PyDev, and XMLEspresso. Yet, when I right click on a file and select Open With, I see no XML Editor choice. What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you right-clicking?

Comment: On the filename in the left hand pane.